# Clustering picture gallery

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, data-visualization, community-wiki

This is a proposed community wiki to collect pictures of
unsupervised clustering of data sets, e.g. k-means
and ANN, approximate nearest neighbors.
Both pictures of clusters themselves, 
and diagrams that help analyze / put numbers on clusterings,
are welcome. (Bad examples can be instructive too.)

Please give `N=`, `dim=` (Nfeature) and `Ncluster=` (k) next to each link.

Edited Monday 31Jan:
Given the many different kinds of clustering (text, images, amazon ...)
and people who do some aspect of clustering (programmers, algorithms guys,
PhDs with papers to write), this wish is naive;
don't see how to organize it.
On the other hand, it might cross-culture / get lots of hits from these different people.

A meta question:
Could one make a picture gallery right on this page, within stats.stackexchange?
By that I mean uniform pictures say 250 pixels wide, instead of having to click each link separately:
nice for users, seems nontrivial to implement, and maybe copyright issues.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why does this question now sit on the Meta?

Comment: It is a request for making a image data base on the site.